# Android Studio (Java): "Unfortunately, Application has Stopped" / OutofMemoryError

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

The code I currently have goes to a new activity with a drawable animation when a button is clicked.  I use this tutorial almost exactly to create an animation with two pictures taken from frames of a video (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html).  The app runs, but when the button is clicked to go to the activity with the animation, a dialog box pops up that says "Unfortunately, application has stopped".

According to logcat:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 56MB until OOM

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I suppose your pictures are in a high resolution. Try downscaling them.

Comment: reducing picture size worked, thanks for your comment!

Comment: I want to add up, you cant be resizing picture everytime.. resample the bitmap http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html